# Why am I getting a nullpointer exception? (Beginner)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am extremely frustrated with this, and have been trying for days to try and fix it. I have two classes, Main and GetNounList

Main:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    GetNounList nouns = new GetNounList();

}// end main method
}//end of Main class
```

GetNounList:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GetNounList extends Main {
ArrayList<String> listOfWords;

public GetNounList() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner list = new Scanner(new File(
    "/Users/FareedMabrouk/Desktop/Explore/Coding/Java/BusinessIdeaGenerator/CodeRepository/BusinessGen/src/Nouns.txt"));

while (list.hasNextLine()) {
        listOfWords.add(list.nextLine());
    } // end while loop
    System.out.println(listOfWords);
}//end constructor
}//end GetNounList class
```

The file has random nouns like this:

```
cat
laptop
dog
headphones
```

etc...

The only error is the nullpointer exception at the line where it is adding the nouns from the file to the arraylist. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: You didn't initialize the list

Answer (score 0):

`listOfWords` was never constructed.

Replace

```
ArrayList<String> listOfWords;
```

with

```
List<String> listOfWords=new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you so much

Comment: you have no idea how much this pissed me off